# Stretch image in iron-image element

Tags: html, css, image, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have an element inside a div : `<div style="width:330px;"><iron-image src="image.png"></iron-image></div>` .
The image is 315px in width and 237px height. I want this image to stretch and make it 330px in width as it the container that is inside of, and the height to be auto to do not break the image ratio.

I have tried this :

```
iron-image {
    width:330px;
    height:auto;
}
iron-image img {
     width:330px;
     height:auto;
}
```

And :

```
<div style="width:330px;"><iron-image src="image.png" style="width:330px;height:auto"></iron-image></div>
```

How do i make the `<img ... >` element inside the `<iron-image>` element stretch to 330px width and automatic height ?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-image)? The `sizing` property may help you here.

Comment: When i add the `sizing` property and set the style of `iron-image` element to `width:330px;height:auto;` the image is just not displayed at all.

Comment: what is the problem that appears ? your css looks fine to me

Comment: The image is displayed at it's original size(315x237), not 330xAuto how i want.

Comment: try (max-height: 100%;display:block;) instead of (height:auto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, the sizing attribute doesn't help me for that, and because the img inside iron-image is under shady DOM, you can access it with ::content.

```css
#imgWrapper {
    width: 330px;
}
iron-image {
    width:100%;
}
iron-image::content img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

and

```
<div id="imgWrapper">
    <iron-image src="image.png"></iron-image>
</div>
```

for ::content to work in light dom (outside of a custom element) don't forget

```
<style is="custom-style">
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: I have the same issue, your solution doesn't give those images auto height.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to do width 100% and height to auto.  This worked for me:

```
<template>
  <style is="custom-style" include="uvalib-theme">
    :host {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    iron-image {
      --iron-image-width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <iron-image width="100%" src="myimg"></iron-image>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398417/how-to-give-polymer-iron-image-auto-height) and found [paper-card](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-card). It works perfectly:

```
<paper-card image="YOUR_IMAGE_URL_HERE">
  <div class="card-content">
     <img src="OR_HERE">
  </div>
</paper-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to update "img" tag style which is "under" (=shadow DOM) the iron-image.

To do so I have updated the style, here is the dart code:

```
querySelectorAll('img').forEach((Element img) {
img.setAttribute('style', 'width:330px;height:auto');
});
```

This code is placed within the PolymerElement "attached" available function (wouldn't work in the "ready" function)

> **attached**  Called after the element is attached to the document.