# How to give polymer iron image auto height?

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

Check out this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/muvupi/edit?html,output)

I want my images have auto height with `sizing="contain"`, it means they won't have extra space. In my example those extra space are in red.

iron image is required to set a fixed height otherwise image not display, I tried `height:auto and height:100%` but not work.

Comment: sizing should be cover

Comment: cover not what i want.  I want to display full image

Answer (score 1):

I was using paper-material, should use [paper-card](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-card)